# program that exports html files and a txt file with account and email details in it, want to colate and email from a text file and convert to pdf

Tags: bash, shell

i have multiple .txt files like this 12345-001.txt and 56789-001.txt in 12345-001.txt i have this info:

I have a problem with Section 1, to read the file name and pass this to the pdf creator as the output pdf file.

Section 2, Reading the .HTM file names and copying the the same name file from 1 directory to another and passing the names to the pdf creator to combine the file into 1 pdf file, some files might have 3 HTM files some can have 10 HTM file depending on the number of sales done to the client

the HTM to PDF converter is working ok.

```
me@gmail.com
INVOICE00100000.HTM
INVOICE00100002.HTM
INVOICE00100003.HTM
```

and in 56789-001.txt i have this info:

```
you@gmail.com
INVOICE00100001.HTM
INVOICE00100004.HTM
INVOICE00100005.HTM
```

the .HTM files are in another directory.

I want to generate a email useing the name of the file as the attachment name and reading the email address inside the file as the send to address and taking the names of the html files copying the files from the htm folder and coverting them to pdf and merging to one pdf and sending it off.

What i have so far is this:

**Section 1**

```
dir="/u/acu/exported-dat/"      //this reads the 12345-001.txt name

ls "$dir" > /u/acu/dirfile      //and writes it to file dirlist

cd /u/acu/exported-dat          //this reads only the 12345-001 and 

ls | while read fname           //writes it to a file called tmpfile

do
echo ${fname%%.*} > /u/acu/tmpfile

done
```

**Section 2**

```
LINES=()                     // this reads the content of 12345-001.txt    

while IFS= read -r line      
do
  echo -E "$line"
 LINES[${#LINES[@]}]="$line"
mailaddr="${LINES[0]}"      // takes the fist line and stores it as mailaddr
echo -E "$mailaddr"
cp $line /u/acu/exported    //reads the rest of the HTM file names and copys
done < /u/acu/dirfile        //them to exported dir from the names in dirlist
                            //   DOES NOT WORK


cdate1=$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)    // this monitors the exported folder and when
folder1="/u/acu/exported"    // the HTM files appear converts them to PDF's

cd $folder1

while file=$(ls "$folder1")
  [ -z "$file" ]
    do sleep 5
    done
        echo "There is a file in the folder at $cdate1"
        if [[ -f $file ]]
    then
        ls
        echo "Converting single File"
        sh /u/runacu/topdf.sh
    else
        echo "Converting Multipule Files"
        sh /u/runacu/topdf.sh
  fi                                        // THIS WORKS
```

**Section 3**

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/u/acu/exported/$OUTFILE.PDF INV00100000.PDF INV00100002.PDF INV00100003.PDF


// this needs to read all the pdfs in exported folder and merge them to 1 pdf file
// SORT OF WORKS dont know how to pass the multiple pdf's to it.
```

**Section 4**

```
OUTFILE="$1"             // the mail attachment 12345-001   
TO="$mailaddr"           // the email address me@gmail.com
SUB="TEST STATEMENT ATTACHMENTS"
MESS="Attached please find the invoices pertaining to your latest Statement"
CCTO="my mail address"
SMTP="mail.saix.co.za"
FROM="DO-NOT-REPLY@GOOGLE.CO.ZA"


/u/runacu/sendEmail.dat -f $FROM -t $TO -u $SUB -m $MESS -cc $CCTO -a /u/acu/exported/$OUTFILE>PDF -s $SMTP:25 -xu me@unisolv.co.za -xp XXXXXXX -l email.log
// this works manually BUT i want to pass the attachment
// files and mail address from the 12345-001.txt file to it
```

## All help will be greatly appreciated

## thank you

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: section 1, to pick up the file name and pass that to the pdf converter to create the pdf file with the file name.  Section 2, Read the content of the file and pass this to the pdf creator to read the names and combine them into 1 pdf,         Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally fixed the program and here is the code that i did to fix it:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
dir="/u/acu/exported-dat"
dest="/u/acu/exported"
fromDat="/u/acu/datlist"
toCopyList="/u/acu/dirlist"

while :
do 
if test "$(ls -A "$dir")"; then
echo "Dat Files still Exist -- Processing..."
#
ls "$dir" > /u/acu/datlist
read -r file < "$fromDat"                  # Read first line of datlist
echo -e "from datlist file $file"          # echo first line of datlist
echo "$file" > /u/acu/dirlist
#
read -r line1 < "$toCopyList"             # Read first line of dirlist
echo -e "from dirlist file $line1"        # echo first line of dirlist
cp /u/acu/exported-dat/$line1 /u/acu/exported/process.dat

linesToSkip=1
{
 for ((i=$linesToSkip;i--;)) ;do
    read
    done
  while read line ;do
    echo $line
     cp /u/acu/exported-htm/$line /u/acu/exported
    done
} < /u/acu/exported/process.dat

read -r mailaddr < /u/acu/exported/process.dat
echo -e "from Process.dat file $mailaddr"   

sh /u/runacu/watchfile.sh
echo " Busy Merging Invoice Files to 1 PDF File."
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=/u/acu/exported/$file.PDF /u/acu/exported-pdf/*
#
TO="$mailaddr"
SUB="UNISOLV TEST STATEMENT ATTACHMENTS"
MESS="Attached please find the invoices pertaining to your latest   Statement" 
CCTO="markb@unisolv.co.za"
SMTP="mail.unisolv.co.za"
FROM="DO-NOT-REPLY@UNISOLV.CO.ZA"
#
echo " Busy Emailing PDF to Customer."
#
/u/runacu/sendEmail.dat -f $FROM -t $TO -u $SUB -m $MESS -cc $CCTO -a   /u/acu/exported/*.PDF -s $SMTP:25 -xu joe@unisolv.co.za -xp X4DubuKe@ -l email.log
#
mv /u/acu/exported-dat/$line1 /u/acu/pdf-sent
mv /u/acu/exported/*.PDF /u/acu/pdf-sent
rm /u/acu/exported-pdf/*
rm /u/acu/exported/*
#
else
 echo "No Dat Files Exist Exiting Mailing Process Now!" ; sleep 60
fi
 done
```